# Combining a one-to-one relationship into one object in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

I have a one-to-one relationship in my database, and I'd like to just combine that into one object in Fluent NHibernate.  The specific tables I am talking about are the aspnet_Users and aspnet_Membership tables from the default ASP.NET Membership implementation.  I'd like to combine those into one simple User object and only get the fields I want.

I would also like to make this read-only, as I want to use the built-in ASP.NET Membership API to modify.  I simply want to take advantage of lazy-loading.

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the `Join` method of Fluent NHibernate to join the tables in your mapping. See James Gregory's [answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345125/nhibernate-domain-object-spans-multiple-tables).

Comment: I added the join, but it doesn't seem to know how to relate the two tables. How can I modify which fields to join?

Comment: I was able to modify the KeyColumn in the join, and this works exactly how I want.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my completed mapping:

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Table("aspnet_Membership");

        Id(x => x.ID, "UserId");
        Map(x => x.EmailAddress, "Email");

        Join("aspnet_Users", m =>
            {
                m.KeyColumn("UserId");
                m.Map(x => x.UserName);
            });
    }
}
```